# Acceptance- vs staging environment

Tags: american-english, british-english

In application development it is common practice to push newly developed versions of code to an environment other then the life environment to have other people test it.

In my previous company we were told by Americans that we couldn't translate the Dutch term 'Acceptatie omgeving' to 'Acceptance environment' because that's not proper English. In my current company however this term is actively used and when I search online dictionaries it seems this word does exist.

Is acceptance environment correct English?
Is it a en_US vs en_UK thing?

**UPDATE**
[Google says](https://www.google.be/search?q=acceptance&oq=acceptance&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59l2j69i61j0l2.1949j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8): the action of consenting to receive or undertake something offered. Or the process or fact of being received as adequate, valid, or suitable.
Which sounds about right to me. So other then the 'weird' feeling, I can't make my case about changing 'Acceptance' to 'Staging'

Comment: The tags are only part of my question, but I couldn't think of anything that was actually applicable.

Comment: Typically you have the "Development", "QA or Testing" "Staging" and "Production" environments. Not sure what "acceptance environment" is.

Comment: Here it is Dev(localhost) => Test => Acceptance (your Staging) => Production

Comment: Yes Staging env is also sometimes called UAT env (User Acceptance Testing)

Comment: So you're saying acceptance environment is perfectly acceptable? If you make it an answer rather than a comment I can vote you

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is seems more appropriate for a programming website than an English language and usage site.

Comment: @DavidM, it's still "English Language Usage", just of a technical nature. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Acceptance environment" is acceptable . However, re-label it as "User Acceptance" environment as this is the term that I have heard more often.

Answer (score 0):

`Acceptance` is correct term. The acronym DTAP is short for `Development, Testing, Acceptance and Production`.[1][2] It is a rather common acronym in ICT expressing a phased approach of software testing and deployment. The four letters in `DTAP` denote the following common steps:

The program or component is developed on a `Development` system. This development environment might have no testing capabilities.
Once the developer thinks it is ready, the product is copied to a `Test` environment, to verify it works as expected. This test environment is supposedly standardized and in close alignment with the target environment.
If the test is successful, the product is copied to an Acceptance test environment. During the `Acceptance` test, the customer will test the product in this environment to verify whether it meets their expectations.
If the customer accepts the product, it is deployed to a `Production` environment, making it available to all users of the system.